# How to use jQuery append() via id when id is present in a localStorage variable?

Tags: jquery, cordova

I want to use jquery append() using an id as my selector, however the id is stored in a local variable. I have the tried the following code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#'+localStorage.productUrl+'').append('<span>item is added</span>');
```

Here is my code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCuKt/20

Comment: what do you mean by "this is not working". what is the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "this is not working". but if `localStorage.productUrl` contains id of the element on which you want to append span then it should work .
Also ensure your jquery is inside.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

**see demo:-**

http://jsfiddle.net/tCuKt/1/

**Edit:- Updated Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/tCuKt/25

Answer (score 0):

I assume you may have forgotten your `document.ready()` as mentioned above, however the double single quotes appended to the end of your selector are pointless as well. This should be what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#' + localStorage.productUrl).append('<span>item is added</span>');
});
```

Comment: i have used this syntex as mentioned above but still this is not working... i have a url path in id localStorage.productUrl.

Comment: @ManishAgrawal If you alert localStorage.productUrl, does it show you the expected result?

Comment: yes after alert it shows correct result and correct length..ok i will show u all working of my project i am making a mobile application of the site www.turrg.com when i touch on a product it shows mw a dialog in this i have add to wishlist and 3 other options.. the dialog box is on the another page now if i touch on add to wishlist link then it should be redirect to previous page and and append a plus sign(+) toi that item..by using li id..that id id present in localStorage.productUrl and the id is a url path of that item so for redirecting to previous page i used history.back()

Comment: so this is the problem ...and if i used document.getElementById() then css is not loaded...what should i do..??  please help me.  thanks

Comment: Is there a field with an id of the productUrl? I kind of need to see your html to help.

Comment: productUrl is an id of a li tag.

Comment: $("#itemList").append('<li id="'+productUrl+'" data-native-menu="false"><a href="index.html#dialogPage" data-native-menu="false" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">' +
         '<img src='+imageUrl+' id="itemImage"/>'+'<spanid="dataName"><h4>'+productName+'</h4></span></a></li>');

Comment: in this code the itemList is an id of ul tag....now i need to append one more span to this li..by using this                  $('#'+productUrl).append('<span>item is added</span>');

Comment: If you created the original li with productUrl, it should work here unless the productUrl is now out of scope. Could you update your questions with more code. It will be much easier to read an understand if it is not in the comments.